# Why are so many colour formats not able to be transferred?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

At [this](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listoptimaltilingformats.php?platform=windows) site it shows supports for formats. If you look at Windows it shows that BC formats are overwhelmingly supported, at 99% but if you look at the transfer destination and source you'll notice that they're about 15 percent less at 85%. How on earth are you supposed to copy your image on these systems that don't support BC transfer?

The example I gave is for BC formats, but the same thing happens on Android with R8G8B8A8_UINT.

Edit: Oops, I just realised I asked a question like this. Any discrepancy between the sampled image support and transfer destination or source support is due to older cards that weren't updated? Any GPU that supports a format for sampling must support it for transfer destination and source, right?

If you look at the R16 formats on Windows, it goes from 99% support generally to about 80% for transfer destination and source.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Vulkan 1.0 drivers implicitly support transfer operations for any format it has any amount of support for.

---

There isn't a format on that list that gets above 85.77% support for TRANSFER_SRC and TRANSFER_DST, even if the format has 100% support for sampling.

Looking at the devices that support [sampling *BC1_RGB_SRGB_BLOCK*](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listdevicescoverage.php?optimaltilingformat=BC1_RGB_SRGB_BLOCK&featureflagbit=SAMPLED_IMAGE&platform=windows), and those that support it as a [transfer destination](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listdevicescoverage.php?optimaltilingformat=BC1_RGB_SRGB_BLOCK&featureflagbit=TRANSFER_DST&platform=windows), we can immediately see some discrepencies in the supported devices on the first page, such as the [NVidia 410](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=123#device). The 410 supports API version 1.0.3, supports sampling many image formats, but doesn't support any format as a transfer destination or source.

According to the Vulkan spec, feature flags [*VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT* and *VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT*](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap40.html#VkFormatFeatureFlagBits) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230823213652/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap40.html#VkFormatFeatureFlagBits)</sub> were added in Vulkan 1.1, and according to the description of those flags, in Vulkan 1.0 (when *VK_KHR_maintenance1* isn't enabled), when the flag bits are not 0 the transfer operations are implied.

> *VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT* specifies that an image can be used as a source image for copy commands. If the application apiVersion is Vulkan 1.0 and *VK_KHR_maintenance1* is not supported, *VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT* is implied to be set when the format feature flag is not 0.

> *VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT* specifies that an image can be used as a destination image for copy commands and clear commands. If the application apiVersion is Vulkan 1.0 and *VK_KHR_maintenance1* is not supported, *VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT* is implied to be set when the format feature flag is not 0.

Comment: How can I found out if a GPU supports Vulkan 1.2 or Vulkan 1.3? I'm having trouble understanding when a feature is required to be supported on a GPU. A card can Vulkan 1.2 but not support a feature that was made core in 1.2. Then in what ways does it support Vulkan 1.2 if it doesn't support a core feature of it?

Comment: You can call [vkEnumerateInstanceVersion](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap4.html#vkEnumerateInstanceVersion) to get the version of the loader. [vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap5.html#vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties) will tell you the version of a device. Device drivers aren't supposed to lie about the version they support. As for whether a feature is required, the [spec](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/index.html) does a pretty good job at telling you.